# Application Errors while attempting to deploy to Heruko

Tags: javascript, heroku, hosting

I'm trying to deploy my app with Heroku, but I get an Application Error. When using `heroku logs --tail`
I get these error messages

```
2022-05-30T00:27:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-05-30T00:27:23.568355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-05-30T00:27:24.633603+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-05-30T00:27:24.633674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:27:24.633784+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-05-30T00:27:24.633884+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-05-30T00:27:24.633985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-05-30T00:27:24.634014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:27:24.634040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-05-30T00:27:24.634074+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-05-30T00:27:24.635150+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-30T00:27:24.635288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-05-30T00:27:24.635390+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-05-30T00_27_24_486Z-debug-0.log
2022-05-30T00:27:24.758912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-30T00:27:24.814082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-30T00:27:24.817776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-30T00:27:26.476033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-05-30T00:27:28.061779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-05-30T00:27:28.061854+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062009+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062116+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062246+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062331+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-05-30T00:27:28.062380+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-05-30T00:27:28.063513+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-30T00:27:28.063667+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-05-30T00:27:28.063789+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-05-30T00_27_27_912Z-debug-0.log
2022-05-30T00:27:28.188410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-30T00:27:28.282463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-30T00:27:29.483975+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=4deb6ac0-a67e-4a72-aee6-01dcd211b517 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:27:29.741362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=918f3603-24e4-42f0-8c75-8253b8f1f583 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:27:45.104222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=8d586690-d95d-475b-89bd-baab31c98dd3 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:28:04.356380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=31102a39-00de-4094-ad98-e3d9b8cb8c99 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:28:05.119256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=d2cdd71f-3a6b-434c-8bb2-30055d3205e2 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:28:05.644465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=d64605e7-9c55-49d0-953e-94acd7c1fb58 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:28:06.240368+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=3a9c689f-0a85-4b19-aa39-5f34b9569677 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-30T00:29:01.723396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-30T00:29:03.348367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949235+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949386+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949551+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949676+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949795+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949840+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949937+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-05-30T00:29:04.949992+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-05-30T00:29:04.951553+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-30T00:29:04.951766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-05-30T00:29:04.951951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-05-30T00_29_04_791Z-debug-0.log
2022-05-30T00:29:05.066491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-30T00:29:05.159310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-30T00:29:07.599371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-sands-33080.herokuapp.com request_id=6f204d6b-a85e-4099-b073-f2b2e6f9c541 fwd="174.62.83.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I don't know what the error is, and how to fix it. It says that the build succeeded, so I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: missing script start means your package.json doesnt have start script?

Comment: _"I don't know what the error is"_: Did you read the log? Missing script: "start" is the problem. Can you add your `package.json` file to the question?

Comment: oh god, I really am a fool. Thanks for the help :D